# Node.js - Mongoose path validation failing - TypeError: Cannot call method 'validate' of undefined

Tags: node.js, model, mongoose, typeerror

I have the following Mongoose schema and path validaion:

```
var locationSchema = new Schema({
    userid: { type: Number, required: true },
    location: {
        type: [{
            type: "String",
            required: true,
            enum: ['Point', 'LineString', 'Polygon'],
            default: 'Point'
        }],
        coordinates: { type: [Number], required:true }

    },
    tags: [{ type: String, index: true, required: true }],
    create_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});


locationSchema.path('location.coordinates').validate(function(coordinates){
        return coordinates && coordinates.toString().match(/([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)$/g);
}, 'Invalid latitude or longitude.');
```

When I start my app i get:

```
locationSchema.path('location.coordinates').validate(function(coordinates){
                                            ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'validate' of undefined
```

Can anyone advise why this is failing? Note is I just validate path('location'), its starts fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a field in an embedded object named `type`, you need to define its type using the explicit object notation or Mongoose thinks it's defining the type of the parent object instead:

```
var locationSchema = new Schema({
    userid: { type: Number, required: true },
    location: {
        type: { type: [{
            type: "String",
            required: true,
            enum: ['Point', 'LineString', 'Polygon'],
            default: 'Point'
        }]},
        coordinates: { type: [Number], required:true }
    },
    tags: [{ type: String, index: true, required: true }],
    create_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyHK that had me stumped!!