# Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm setting up my model incorrectly here somehow and I can't see it.  I've looked at this issue:

[Node.js - Mongoose path validation failing - TypeError: Cannot call method 'validate' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290928/node-js-mongoose-path-validation-failing-typeerror-cannot-call-method-vali/26291139#26291139)

and I don't think it's the solution I'm after.  I'm trying to setup a simple document that has one nested object, and another nested array of objects.  I keep getting this error:

```
Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined
```

Here is the code I'm trying to run.

```
var mapSchema = new Schema({
map_key : {
    i : {
        type : Number,
        required : 'Map Key i required'
    },
    j : {
        type : Number,
        required : 'Map Key j required'
    },
    k : {
        type : Number,
        required : 'Map Key k required'
    }
},
tiles : [ {
    x : {
        type : Number,
        required : 'Tile x required'
    },
    y : {
        type : Number,
        required : 'Tile y required'
    },
    tile_type : {
        type : Number,
        required : 'Tile type required'
    }
} ]
});

mapSchema.path('map_key').validate(function(value, next) {
    mapService.findMap(value, function(err, map) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return next(false);
        }
        next(!map);
    });
}, 'Map already created');
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

UPDATE:  For whatever it's worth, I've tried taking the model down to its simplest form without success:

```
var mapSchema = new Schema({
map_key : {
    i :  Number,

    j : Number,

    k :  Number

},
tiles : [ {
    x :  Number,

    y :  Number,

    tile_type : Number
} ]
});

mapSchema.path('map_key').validate(function(value, next) {
    mapService.findMap(value, function(err, map) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return next(false);
        }
        next(!map);
    });
}, 'Map already created');
```

UPDATE.. again.. So I went so for as to remove the map_key object and change the validator to the tiles object to try and narrow things down.  I do not get the error when I remove the map_key object :

```
var mapSchema = new Schema({
tiles : [ {
    x :  Number,

    y :  Number,

    tile_type : Number
} ]
});

mapSchema.path('tiles').validate(function(value, next) {
mapService.findMap(value, function(err, map) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return next(false);
    }
    // If the map exists, return false, else it will be null.
    next(!map);
});
}, 'Map already created');
```

So my guess is the error has something to do with the map_key and the way it's setup, but I still got nothing in terms of what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. So I got it working.  Not entirely sure why this works, everything in the docs shows it the way I had it above originally.  I had to place the entire map_key object within it's own type.  Again not sure why it has be that way, but at least I'm up and running again.  Here is my solution for what it's worth to anyone else who might have a similar issue.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var mapService = require('../services/map-service');

var mapSchema = new Schema({
    map_key : {type:{
        i : {
            type : Number,
            required : 'Map Key i required'
        },
        j : {
            type : Number,
            required : 'Map Key j required'
        },
        k : {
            type : Number,
            required : 'Map Key k required'
        }
    }},
    tiles : [{
            x : {
                type : Number,
                required : 'Tile x required'
            },
            y : {
                type : Number,
                required : 'Tile y required'
            },
            tile_type : {
                type : Number,
                required : 'Tile type required'
            }
        }
    ]
});

mapSchema.path('map_key').validate(function(value, next) {
    mapService.findMap(value, function(err, map) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return next(false);
        }

        next(!map);
    });
}, 'Map already created');

var Map = mongoose.model('Map', mapSchema);

module.exports = {
    Map : Map
};
```